# How to export database using mysqldump in php?

Tags: php, mysql, web

I aleady have a code here and it works when I use it on the command prompt directly using this `cd C:\wamp......` to point out the bin and use the following code below to dump:

```
<?php

DEFINE("HOST","localhost");                         // Host Name
DEFINE("USER","root");                              // Database Username
DEFINE("PASSWORD","");                              // Database Password
DEFINE("DATABASE","db_osgamdrp");                   // Database Name
DEFINE("TIMEZONE","Asia/Manila");                   // Server Timezone
DEFINE("BIN","C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin")   // MySQLi BIN

$Status = 1;
$Message = "";

$Command = "mysqldump --opt -h " . HOST . " -u " . USER . " -p " . PASSWORD . "" . DATABASE . " > ../../../../../resources/database_backup/" . DATABASE . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . ".gz";

if (!exec($Command)) { 
    $Status = 0;
    $Message    = "Something Went Wrong. Please Try Again";
}
?>
```

Whats wrong with this code? Its not working.

Comment: "Is not working" is not an adequate description.  What exactly are you expecting, and what happens instead?

Comment: when i use it directly on the command prompt its working  and it backups the database but in when it is executed in php. nothing happens..

Comment: here's the command structure in php: exec($command,$output,$worked);